# What is the error with setPreferredSpeed Unit?

Tags: anylogic

[image]

what's the problem???!!!

Isn't the unit MPS?

Comment: btw: Please put some effort into your question title and content, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This helps others with similar issues in the future, feel free to edit your question a little :)

Answer (score 0):

Your agent type is not set to be used as a Car:
[image]

Only then does AnyLogic know the function.

PS: Always use code-complete when coding (Ctrl+space). For normal agents, it does not show a function, indicating that it does not exist.

But if you flag your agent as a "Car", it will show up.

Comment: I flagged my agent as a "Car" but error exists..

Comment: Works here, then you need to refine your question to add more details so it can be duplicated.